# create a variable in a df based on combination of values located in another df in R

Tags: r, function, filter

beginner in r! i'd like to create a variable (newvar) in my df that is based on values of other variables within my df (x, y, z). an external file (exfile) has 4 columns with all the possible combination of x, y, and z in first 3 columns and the 4th column (answer) has the value i'd like the newvar to be. i could do manually using mutate() + case_when() and list all the combinations, however, there are many many combinations, so i decided to write a simple function.

exfile looks like this:

[exfile image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYALy.png)

```
foo <- function (x, y, z) {

  exfile <- read.csv("exfile.csv")
  exfile %>% filter (x==x, y==y, z==z) %>%
  select (answer) %>% as.numeric (.) -> x

return (x)

}
```

it works fine if i simply input numbers, but when i use it with my df:

```
df %>%
  mutate (newvar = foo(x, y, z))-> df
```

the problem is i can't pass vectors in filter(), so i get error message: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length.

again, there are many many combinations, so it'd not be possible to do a bunch of if()s in the function...

what should i do?

thank you!

edit: i've tried doing %in% instead of ==, and get this error message instead: 
Error in function_list[k] : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

update: inner_join() is a solution to the problem! thanks all!

Comment: Can you show a small sample of how `exfile` and `df` look like? Do you need to replace `==` with `%in%` in `filter`?

Comment: Are the column names always x, y, z

Comment: If you want all the possible combinations,then do `crossing(x, y, z)`

Comment: Sounds like a simple merge on x, y, z.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for responding, edited above to respond!

Comment: @akrun yes, column names always the same

Comment: If you can update your post with a small reproducible example using `dput` and expected output, it may be easier to understand the issue

Comment: @Edward yes, inner_join() seems to have solve this! thank you! though i'm still curious if there's a way a function can do this?

Comment: `inner_join` __is__ a function. Why re-invent the wheel?